# how can my code work for small lists but breaks on bigger lists?

Tags: python

So i am trying to learn python and i am going through codewars practice problems, this one has had my stumped so i have come here for help.

promtp:

> You get an array of numbers, return the sum of all of the positives
>   ones.
>
> Example [1,-4,7,12] => 1 + 7 + 12 = 20
>
> Note: if there is nothing to sum, the sum is default to 0.

my code:

```
def positive_sum(arr):
    for item in arr:
        if item**3 < 0:
            arr.remove(item)

    if sum(arr) > 0:
        ans = sum(arr)
        return ans 
    return 0
```

[passed all tests except for the 40 random ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5UxH.png)

any help would be awesome 
thanks :P

Comment: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1207406)

Comment: But why not the much simpler: `sum = 0; for item in arr: if item > 0: sum += item; return sum`?

Comment: more efficient would be to use list comprehension -- `sum(x for x in arr if x> 0)`

Comment: @RajatMishra Technically that's a generator expression rather than a list comprehension - it's better since it avoids allocating a list in the first place. :)